# How to seperate two Ints from a ReadLine in C#

Tags: c#

How might I take a "Console.ReadLine()" in C# and divide it into two ints?
Lets say that I have this

```
Please enter your #'s: 123 234
your two #'s were 123 and 234
```

how might I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your line in isn't that complex you could use

string.Split

Example:

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file))
  {
     string lineIn = string.Empty;
     while ((lineIn = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
     {
        string[] numbersAsStrings = lineIn.Split(' ');
     }
   }
```

Comment: Actually, all I had to do was

Comment: string lineIn = Console.ReadLine();
            string[] numbersAsStrings = lineIn.Split(' ');
            Console.WriteLine(numbersAsStrings[0]);
            Console.WriteLine(numbersAsStrings[1]);

Answer (score 5):

Try something like this:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var input = Console.ReadLine();

        var values = input.Split(' ')
            .Select(int.Parse);
    }
}
```

If you are concerned about users entering multiple spaces between numbers you can do this:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var input = Console.ReadLine();

        var values = input.Split(new[] {" "}, 
                StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                    .Select(int.Parse);
    }
}
```

Now both of these examples will blow up of course if the user doesn't supply a value or if the values are non-numeric.  This should get you started on the right path though.

Answer (score 1):

If you are expecting more than one space between integers, you can do a Regex Split:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var str = Console.ReadLine();

            Regex regex = new Regex(@"\s+");
            var intArrary = regex.Split(str).Select(x => int.Parse(x));
        }
    }
```